# Work with InputTextBox in corona under windows environment

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create a login screen for user but couldn't able to see text box on simulator. I am using Windows 7 as development environment. How can I debug it under windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

Corona provides a debugger (Corona.Debugger.exe in the Corona SDK folder), but it requires you to debug your script from the command line (this is an example of a debugging session: http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/corona-simulator-and-debugger-sample-debugging-session).

I've recently added Corona debugging support to [ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com), which gives you a way to debug your Corona scripts from an IDE environment. You'll need to use the latest code from github to access this functionality until the next release is out.

Another option is using Koneki (Eclipse integration for Lua) as described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/877098/).

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have to do a "Build for Device", install it on the device and test it there.

Comment: What is "Build for Device"? Where can I get it.

Comment: It's under the Simulator's File->Build menu.  If your on Windows you can use the CTRL-B short cut, or CMD-B on a Mac.  The shortcuts for Android are SHIFT-CTRL-B or SHIFT-CMD-B.

Comment: It will be very time taking to debug any app when I make small changes in app and each time I have to deploy app on device?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite late, but maybe can be useful...

To test directly on corona simulator on windows you can use this plugin, that simulates textfields/textboxes behaviour:

https://github.com/ProGM/CoronaSDK-win-native

Answer (score 0):

When you are running Corona on window machine, It does not support text box on simulator.
 So you need to check it on device.